# Kivy - NotImplementedError: tostring() has been removed

Tags: python, linux, kivy

its been days since iam stuck with this error. As you can see in the log have latest version of Kivy and Python but i get PermissionError and NotImplementedError. i tryed to run it as superuser but it still doesnot work, as i know it must work without it.

when i run it a window appears but it doesnot render any text at all, there is only one artifact in the midle wich disapears when i click the button, everything else seems to be fine.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Hello World')

TestApp().run()



[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/shalva/.kivy/logs/kivy_17-01-16_7.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.6.0 (default, Dec 24 2016, 08:03:08)
[GCC 6.2.1 20160830]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 13.0.3'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile '>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event6
[INFO              ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event6>
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO              ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
 Exception in thread Thread-1:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/input/providers/mtdev.py", line 219, in _thread_run
     _device = Device(_fn)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/lib/mtdev.py", line 131, in __init__
     self._fd = os.open(filename, os.O_NONBLOCK | os.O_RDONLY)
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/input/event6'

 Exception ignored in: 'kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.set_texture'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy/graphics/texture.pyx", line 786, in kivy.graphics.texture.Texture.bind (kivy/graphics/texture.c:10206)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 628, in _texture_fill
     self.render(real=True)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 573, in render
     return self._render_real()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/text/__init__.py", line 559, in _render_real
     data = self._render_end()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py", line 57, in _render_end
     self._pil_im.mode.lower(), self._pil_im.tostring())
   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 697, in tostring
     "Please call tobytes() instead.")
 NotImplementedError: tostring() has been removed. Please call tobytes() instead.
[INFO              ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about the PermissionError, but I can help solve the NotImplementedError. This may, in turn, solve the PermissionError.

You are using the Python module PIL, which used to have a function `tostring()`, but it has been changed to `tobytes()` instead. However, the kivy package has not been updated, so it still calls `tostring()`, which has been deprecated.

So, go to

> /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/text/text_pil.py

on your machine and change line 57 from

```
 self._pil_im.mode.lower(), self._pil_im.tostring())
```

to

```
 self._pil_im.mode.lower(), self._pil_im.tobytes())
```

This should solve you problem.

When you try to edit the file, it may say that you don't have the required permissions to edit them. If so, then I'd recommend typing in the Command Line (or Terminal/Any bash console) `sudo idle`. Then, from idle, open up the file and edit it. (NB you can edit it anyway you like with `sudo` e.g. `sudo nano` etc).

Comment: Thanks, text is rendered. iam still getting PermissionError but it doesnot seem to have any effect... Last Kivy release was 1 year ago and on github they have a lot of activity, why they'r not releasing a new version?

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili, I'm not sure. It maybe that it is designed to work with and older version of PIL (befrore `tostring` was removed). Or you somehow haven't got the most recent version...? I wouldn't worry about it. Feel free to post this fix (link to this page if you like) somewhere where Kivy devs will see it (maybe Github?), they might be able to explain why it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: And if this solved your error, please mark it as 'answered' by clicking on the tick below the upvote/downvote symbols.